# Want to put button instead of link in mail

Tags: php

I want to convert the link to the button in PHP mail.php file.

```
$message = sprintf($this->language->get('mail_message'), $store_name, $link);
```

I will appreciate if someone helps me to convert the link to the button.

Comment: hmm, do you know html? http://www.w3schools.com/html/ ?

Comment: @Eugen that's a bit mean, even if your point is valid.

Comment: @kabanus why? his next question maybe looks like "how i can convert image.jpg to image?"...

Comment: @Eugen Mr. I know very well, I am new in php coding so I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you have to send **html email** instead of **plain/text email**. It is pretty simple, leave the images on the server and send the PHP + CSS to them...

```
$to = 'xyz@example.com';

$subject = 'Subject';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: abc@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$message = '<p><a href="url.php">Anchor Text</a></p>';


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: and `href="url.php"` that will look for a local file on a person's PC; it requires a full URL

Comment: `$message .=` actually, that will throw an undefined variable notice.